# How can I turn one computer into a server for two others?

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

I am using three Windows 7 computers. Is there a way for me to turn one of the computers into a shared computer (i.e. a server), and set it to be accessible only by the other two PCs?

Comment: Like a file server or a remote desktop sever? I'm just confused what you mean by Shared computer?

Comment: all i want is too share files but have it secured aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [Windows HomeGroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/homegroup) for something like this as long as you are talking about a LAN share @ home (HomeGroup would also work for a small business w/o a central file server).

Answer (score 0):

You might find the HomeGroup guide on the MS site to be of some help: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/homegroup-from-start-to-finish